# How to convert input string into data table

Tags: c#, .net

Data:

> itemno: 223344; trn_id: 112233; status:delivered

Data Table :

| itemno | trn_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 223344 | 112233 | delivered |

I want to convert input has data table so that it will be easy for me on filter data on data table based on item.

```cs
foreach (DataRow row2 in responcedt.Rows)
{
    string[] lines = new string[] { row2.Field<string>("ResponseMsg") } ;
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        string[] split = line.Split(';');
        DataRow row1 = table.NewRow();
        row1.SetField(itemno, split[0]);
        row1.SetField(trn_id, split[1]);
        row1.SetField(status, split[2]);
        table.Rows.Add(row1);
    }
}
```

Comment: normal `class(object)` is even easier to filter, so why use `datatable`?

Comment: Better to create class with property and use lambda.

Comment: oh , there are 1000 of records everyday .. so i want filter out itemno value in that .futher process.

Comment: My approach to this situation would be: "how do I split the individual key:values up?", then "how do I separate the key from the value?", and then "how do I construct a datatable with colums for a set of keys?" before finally "how do I populate a datatable with values?" - how far have you got with this process?

Comment: what is the format of data? is it json from api ?

Comment: @Amit The data is provided in the question: `KEY: VALUE; KEY: VALUE; KEY: VALUE`

Comment: @Amit  .. how to use lambda in that case..  i am getting many records of response msgs.. so i want filer only particular itemno .

Comment: what is the structure of your thousands of records ? in string as you mentioned. how are you distinguishing the different records ? I have doubt that you are getting thousands of records in response in this format.

Answer (score 0):

Try following.  If reading from a file replace StringReader with StreamReader :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string pattern = @"(?'key'[^:]+):(?'value'[^;]+);?";
            string input =
                "itemno: 223344; trn_id: 112233; status:delivered\n" +
                "itemno: 223344; trn_id: 112233; status:delivered\n" +
                "itemno: 223344; trn_id: 112233; status:delivered\n" +
                "itemno: 223344; trn_id: 112233; status:delivered\n";

            StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);
            string line = "";
            int row = 0;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(line, pattern);
                    var keyValues = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => new { key = x.Groups["key"].Value, value = x.Groups["value"].Value.Trim() }).ToList();
                    if (++row == 1)
                    {
                        foreach (var keyvalue in keyValues)
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add(keyvalue.key, typeof(string));
                        }
                    }
                    DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();
                    foreach (var keyvalue in keyValues)
                    {
                        newRow[keyvalue.key] = keyvalue.value;
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, turn the desired string into a `dictionary`, and then navigate the dictionary, map each of its members to a `column`, and place each created column in a `row`, and at the end of the row into a `datatable`.

```
string lines = "itemno: 223344; trn_id: 112233; status:delivered\n" +
     "itemno: 223344; trn_id: 112233; status:delivered\n" +
     "itemno: 223344; trn_id: 112233; status:delivered\n";
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

int counter = 0;
foreach (var line in lines.Split('\n'))
{
   var dict = line.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
     .Select(part => part.Split(':'))
     .ToDictionary(split => split[0], split => split[1]);


   DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
   foreach (var key in dict.Keys)
   {
      if(counter == 0)
      {
         DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
         column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
         column.ColumnName = key;
         column.AutoIncrement = false;
         column.Caption = key;
         dataRow.Table.Columns.Add(column);
      }
                    
      dataRow[key] = dict[key];
   }
   counter++;
   dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
```